# no matching manifest for windows/amd64

Tags: docker

Whenever I pull this image I get the error "no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries".  I've uninstalled/reinstalled Docker and get the same results.  I'm not sure what I am missing.

Here's the terminal output:

```
> docker image pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:ltsc2019
ltsc2019: Pulling from windows/servercore
no matching manifest for windows/amd64 10.0.17134 in the manifest list entries

> docker info  -f '{{.OSType}}/{{.Architecture}}'
'windows/x86_64'
```

My environment:

- Windows 10
- the latest Docker edge version
- Docker experimental features are turned on
- switched to Windows Containers

Answer (score 11):

Problem went away when I used a version that matched my host OS version of Windows 10.

```
> docker image pull mcr.microsoft.com/windows/servercore:1803
1803: Pulling from windows/servercore
```

[Windows container version compatibility](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/windowscontainers/deploy-containers/version-compatibility)

> Because Windows Server containers and the underlying host share a
>   single kernel, the container’s base image must match that of the host.
>   If the versions are different, the container may start, but full
>   functionally isn't guaranteed.